# Reading hdf4 files in R

Tags: r, gis, hdf

I have some hdf4 files which I want to read in R.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772341/reading-hdf-files-into-r-and-converting-them-to-geotiff-rasters) answer to use `gdalUtils` package.
But the following code gives me a warning and it doesn't work.

```
gdalinfo(file.path)
NULL
Warning messages:
1: In gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan = ignore.full_scan, verbose = verbose) :
 No GDAL installation found. Please install 'gdal' before continuing:
- www.gdal.org (no HDF4 support!)
- www.trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ (with HDF4 support RECOMMENDED)
- www.fwtools.maptools.org (with HDF4 support)

2: In gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan = ignore.full_scan, verbose = verbose) :
  If you think GDAL is installed, please run:
gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan=FALSE)
```

This suggestion also didn't work
    `gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan=FALSE)`

Do you know of any other package or way to read HDF4 files in R?

Comment: Why don't you try to do what suggests your warning? `No GDAL installation found` means that you need to install `gdal` first. On windows, installing library `rgdal` in R should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

**For Mac users**:  I had the same issue.  I followed the instructions [here](https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/gdal/).

Which consisted of downloading the most recent GDAL framework from [here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks).

and then running the command:

```
echo 'export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```